# fabric.js canvas.toSVG is not a function

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using `Fabric.js version: "1.7.11"`. I am trying to use `toSVG()`, but it is giving me this error.

> canvas.toSVG is not a function.

Why am i getting this response? And how do I solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. But please, really, read the ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article, because you are not showing any proof that what you say is the case, is actually the case. Right now the only answer we can give is "well, obviously, that `.toSVG` property is not a function, if it even exists at all" so you *really* need to show us some code (but, only the relevant code, nothing else) if you would like help.

Comment: its working fine, you can [check](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/jQ3ZZ/145/)

Answer (score 1):

I found why it was doing this. When you download Fabric.js, make sure that the check boxes for "Remove SVG import" and "Remove SVG export" are UNCHECKED.

Thank you and good luck to all.